# RavenDB - How to backpopulate "old" documents after adding new property to POCO?

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, ravendb, database, nosql

I'm just starting to learn about NoSQL/Document storage this morning. I am used to EntityFramework/SQLServer.

My questions is the following: If I have a bunch of "documents" stored and somewhere down the line I add a property to my class that is needed by my app, how do I back-populate the already existing records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the model after the fact then you have a few options.

If you have a default value for the additional field and can wait until the next time that entity is saved for the database then you can simply add the new property and set the value to the defaultv value in the constructor.

You can use a IDocumentConversionListener (http://ayende.com/blog/66563/ravendb-migrations-rolling-updates)

You can also use https://github.com/khalidabuhakmeh/RavenMigrations which I have never used but it seems like it would do what you want.

Comment: Thanks! Ayendes blog post answers many of my questions. I'll look into the migrations library.